# Laravel with docker database error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I know there're similar questions but the answers do not help.

I have this server where I have previously installed the following two repositories:

- [evertramos / docker-wordpress](https://github.com/evertramos/docker-wordpress)
- [evertramos / docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion).

Now I have added a Laravel Application. The Laravel application is now working, the domain is correctly resolved by the Nginx proxy and Letsencrypt is working properly.

However, the problem is now with the database connection. When I run `php artisan migrate --seed` the following errors show up:

In Connection.php line 671:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
> Name does not resolve (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
> where table_schema = mydb and table_name = migrations and table_type =
> 'BASE TABLE')
>
> In Connector.php line 70:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
> Name does not resolve
>
> In Connector.php line 70:
> PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name
> does      not resolve

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
    default:
       external:
         name: ${NETWORK}

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: app-webserver
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${LETSENCRYPT_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: app-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: app-php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${LETSENCRYPT_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
    expose:
      - "9000"

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php

  npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
```

Inside the Laravel `.env` file I have tried all possible values for `DB_HOST`:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_HOST=app-mysql
```

Currently, I have it set up for the MySQL container name:

```
DB_HOST=app-mysql
```

Other values are:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
```

And I still get that error.

I have tried the ping command from the app-php container to the app-mysql container as follows:

```
$ docker exec -ti app-php ping app-mysql
```

I do get response:

```
64 bytes from 172.18.x.x: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.132 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.x.x: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.240 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.x.x: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.207 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.x.x: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.208 ms
```

However, if I run:

```
$ docker-compose run --rm artisan ping app-mysql
```

I get the following error:

> Command "ping" is not defined.

Now if I run `docker-compose up` in order to see what's going on (without `-d`), I see the following, as for MySQL:

```
app-mysql | 2020-07-29T15:43:24.159355Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
app-mysql | 2020-07-29T15:43:24.159523Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
app-mysql | 2020-07-29T15:43:24.159582Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
app-mysql | 2020-07-29T15:43:24.159688Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Does anybody out there know how to fix this? Why can't Artisan or the PHP container connect to the database container?

**workaround**

I solved this using *Laradock* instead

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have just added some debug results at the end. One thing to highlight is `[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306`, but then what does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

I hope this could be helpful for those who have gone through the solution and not yet succeeded. I had similar problem and tried to change the DB_HOST localhost to 127.0.0.1  also with the name of the container/db host (as mentioned in docker-compose), yet I could not get this error resolved. So I updated my .env file like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=3308 or any other port
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_user_name
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```

which started working. I am not assuring it works 100% but you could give a try for this in case other option are not working.

Cheers!

Comment: This was the simplest answer, and it did it for me. I'd be curious to know what the 'host.docker.internal' does, though.

Answer (score 3):

In short: add `Sail` before `PHP` command.

Detailed:

When you prompt a command, you use the local PHP library. That's why you got an error because your local PHP is addressing to docker-mysql connection, on local machine you don't haven a connection like this. When you are using Laravel Sail, you should prompt the command

```
sail PHP artisan migrate
```

which means, you are prompting from Docker's PHP library

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing `container_name: app-mysql`
inside of docker compose network you should use host name `app-mysql`

the easies way to check is to connect to php container and try ping `app-mysql` and then use mysql console to test connection. In this way you at least can find where is the problem.

by the way, since it is docker compose - you must do `docker compose down` and `docker compose up -d` each time you are doing changes in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: I have tested with ping. The PHP container does get reply from the Mysql. However, if I ping from the Artisan container, it says `ping command not found`. I have set the `DB_HOST` of the Laravel's `.env` file to `DB_HOST=app-mysql`. However, I get the same error. I ran simply `docker-compose up` without `-d` and in the Mysql part I see this: `[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: `ping command not found` - not a problem, it's just not installed.


`[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306`  that is a correct behavior. it says that it will use any ip of this container.

you can also try using static IPs for everything, like this:
`networks:`
`      default:`
`        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6`

Comment: looks like in your case for some reason docker compose fails to resolve name into IP, though it is docker compose duty.
so static IPs for everything may be a solution for your dev environment.

Comment: You save my time, good answer, thank you